# Do i need to use embedded maven for m2e workspace resolution to work?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

In my previous pc I was working with linux, eclipse Indigo, m2e (I suppose v1.2 or v1.3) and maven 2.

I had configured m2e to use my external maven 2 installation, had projectA depend on projectB and without the need to install any of the projects to the maven local repository I could execute an Eclipse Maven Build (e.g: compile or dependency:tree) configured to use the external maven installation and to Resolve artifacts in workspace. That worked.

Now, I 'm using win7, eclipse kepler, m2e 1.4.1 and maven 3. I configured all in the same fashion (use external maven installation), create the same projects, use the same eclipse Maven build (run configuration) with workspace artifact resolution enabled and it don't work.

Right now it only works if i configure the maven build to use the internal eclipse embedded maven installation.

I 'd really like to always use my external instalation, does anyone knows if this feature was removed from m2e or should this scenario work as I expected and maybe it's a bug thats happening in my specific environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've tested in other similar environments obtaining same results but, when
upgraded to Eclipse Luna problem was solved.

If you 're facing similar problem, then upgrade to Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking that the `settings.xml` for your external maven makes sense, and eclipse is configured to use it.

Comment: good tip David, in fact my settings.xml does make sense as using non-snapshots (installed) dependencies always work. And about eclipse being configured both global and user configurations of m2e are pointing to the same settings.xml (the only one I have, the global settings.xml inside the maven conf folder).

So I guess, you 're suggesting that this does work for you or that it should work for me. Thank you at least I discard m2e dropping that feature.